# I enabling amazon payments module and if I enable this module shipping cost and tax are not displaying at the one step checkout page in magento2.2.4?

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4

I enabling amazon payments module and if I enable this module shipping cost and tax are not displaying at the one step checkout page. Could you please help me?